# Does infectious hemophilia exist?

Tags: blood, infectious-diseases

Coagulopathies or bleeding disorders, like hemophilia, and Von Willebrand's syndrome, are diseases in which the blood's ability to coagulate is impaired.

But, is there an infectious disease that can be considered a coagulopathy?

I ask because I am writing a story with a disease caused by a virus that impairs coagulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not call it *hemophilia*, but [viral hemorrhagic fevers](https://www.cdc.gov/vhf/diseases.html) involve coagulopathy (quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_hemorrhagic_fever)):

> small blood clots form in blood vessels throughout the body, removing platelets necessary for clotting from the bloodstream and reducing clotting ability. DIC is thought to cause bleeding in Rift Valley, Marburg, and Ebola fevers.

Ebola would be the disease probably most commonly known to the popular consciousness, but you'll see from that Wikipedia page that there are quite a few virus families that cause similar symptoms, and the severity of those symptoms varies widely.

For more on the mechanism of the coagulation aspect of ebola, see:

[Geisbert, T. W., Young, H. A., Jahrling, P. B., Davis, K. J., Kagan, E., & Hensley, L. E. (2003). Mechanisms underlying coagulation abnormalities in ebola hemorrhagic fever: overexpression of tissue factor in primate monocytes/macrophages is a key event. The Journal of infectious diseases, 188(11), 1618-1629.](https://doi.org/10.1086/379724)

Comment: For a scientific article, there is https://doi.org/10.1086/379724

Comment: @ChrisRogers Added as a reference, thanks.

Comment: @Bryan Krause  The CDC has a long list of viral hemorrhagic fevers with a lot of interesting detail.  Maybe this link could also be added to the answer.  https://www.cdc.gov/vhf/diseases.html

Comment: @DianaPetitti Replaced the hemorrhagic fever link to point to that site instead, and moved the Wiki link to just refer to the quote on mechanism.

Comment: @Bryan Krause  Great.  The story can now be set in a lot of exotic places!  I didn't know there were so many viruses that can cause hemorrhagic fever.